# Broadcasting custom function

Tags: python, numpy, broadcast

I want to build a custom function that is supported by broadcasting.

In particular, I have two arrays, one of dates and another of times, and I want to merge the two, as in `datetime.datetime.combine`.

I would like to have something like this (that's the values I have, but the problem is more general):

```
x = array([datetime.date(2019, 1, 21), datetime.date(2019, 1, 21),
           datetime.date(2019, 1, 21)])
y = array([datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 15), datetime.time(0, 30)]
```

And I would like to do something like this:

```
datetime.combine(out[:,0], out[:,1])
```

To get the same result of:

```
np.asarray([datetime.combine(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y)])
```

**More generally:**

Suppose I have a function `f(a,b)`, and I have two numpy arrays `x,y`. Is there a way to apply broadcasting rules and obtain `f(x,y)`?

Comment: Are you trying to vectorize a python function across a numpy array?

Comment: Also, I don't think broadcast means what you think it means...

Comment: To answer your last question: it depends on `f`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist as far as the first answer is concerned, yes, and I would like to avoid np.vectorize. The more general part is a generalization of the first: I miswrote it. In my example there's a vectorialization problem and, if I got the broadcasting meaning right, in the latter part I assume that the two arrays might be of different sizes (but eligible for broadcasting).

Comment: no.vectorize is the straight forward solution, or no.frompyfunc if an object dtype is ok.

Comment: Unless you work with numpy types, you won't get much mileage from numpy arrays that contain references to full blown python objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A custom `ufuncs` is fine if you want to dig into `c` code. But your illustrative case works with `datetime` objects.  `np.frompyfunc` can be quite useful for that.  With object dtype arrays, `numpy` has to iterate at a (near) Python level, running Python code on each of the objects. If you call a `ufunc` on an object array, it delegates the task to a corresponding method of each object (and fails it such a method does not exist).

Lets construct your date arrays:

```
In [20]: from datetime import datetime   

In [35]: alist = [datetime(2019,1,21,0,0), datetime(2019,1,21,0,10),datetime(2020,1,21,0,0)]                                                           
In [36]: x = np.array([a.date() for a in alist])                                
In [37]: y = np.array([a.time() for a in alist])                                
In [38]: x                                                                      
Out[38]: 
array([datetime.date(2019, 1, 21), datetime.date(2019, 1, 21),
       datetime.date(2020, 1, 21)], dtype=object)
In [39]: y                                                                      
Out[39]: 
array([datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(0, 10), datetime.time(0, 0)],
      dtype=object)
```

And do the combine with a list comprehension:

```
In [41]: np.array([datetime.combine(i,j) for i, j in zip(x,y)])                 
Out[41]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 10),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 21, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

and with `frompyfunc`:

```
In [43]: np.frompyfunc(datetime.combine, 2,1)(x,y)                              
Out[43]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 10),
       datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 21, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

With `frompyfunc` we can apply broadcasting

```
In [44]: np.frompyfunc(datetime.combine, 2,1)(x,y[:,None])                      
Out[44]: 
array([[datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 0),
        datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 0),
        datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 21, 0, 0)],
       [datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 10),
        datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 10),
        datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 21, 0, 10)],
       [datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 0),
        datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 21, 0, 0),
        datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 21, 0, 0)]], dtype=object)
```

`x` could have been constructed with `frompyfunc`:

```
In [46]: np.frompyfunc(lambda a: a.date(),1,1)(alist)                           
Out[46]: 
array([datetime.date(2019, 1, 21), datetime.date(2019, 1, 21),
       datetime.date(2020, 1, 21)], dtype=object)
```

---

The `frompyfunc` version of combine is a bit faster

```
In [47]: timeit np.frompyfunc(datetime.combine, 2,1)(x,y)                       
5.39 µs ± 181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [48]: timeit np.array([datetime.combine(i,j) for i, j in zip(x,y)])          
11.8 µs ± 66.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

though a good chunk of the [48] time comes from the array interface:

```
In [51]: timeit [datetime.combine(i,j) for i, j in zip(x,y)]                    
3.91 µs ± 41.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`combine` from list versions of `x` and `y` is even faster.

```
In [52]: %%timeit xy=zip(x.tolist(),y.tolist()) 
    ...: [datetime.combine(i,j) for i,j in xy] 
190 ns ± 0.579 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something more than numpy.vectorize, you may want to checkout numpy ufuncs:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/ufuncs.html

and you may try to create your own custom ufunc
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html